# how to Replace 4th occurence of | with space in each row in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following huge random data

```
1231286234|453|1234|xxx|aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
1231286234|453|1234|xxx| aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
1231286234|453|1234|xxx |aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
1231286234|453|1234|xxx | aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
```

the lines are huge and data is random, i want them to be like

```
1231286234|453|1234|xxx aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
1231286234|453|1234|xxx aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv    
1231286234|453|1234|xxx aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
1231286234|453|1234|xxx aabbc|xcvxcvxcv|xcvxcvxcv|Xcvxcvxcv
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for the sample you have provided.

```
Find what: (\w*\|\w*\|\w*\|\w*)([\|\s]*)([\w\|]*)
Replace with: \1 \3

Search mode: Regular expression
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Actually, there are more than 900 lines. and i just noticed after replacing the first 4th occurrence of | it does not do it in next line, instead it does it in same line.

Comment: Then you have more than 7 |-symbols on each line?

Comment: yes 9 | symbols. But i only want to replace the 4th occurrence from each line. after replacing the 4th it should replace the next 4th from the second line and so on.

Comment: Then you're sample data is incorrect :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer so it works with 9 |-symbols. You can use this for "Find what": (\w*\|\w*\|\w*\|\w*)([\|\s]*)(\w*\|\w*\|\w*\|\w*|\w*\|\w*)

Comment: Or shorter: (\w*\|\w*\|\w*\|\w*)([\|\s]*)([\w\|]*)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^|]+\|){3}.*?\K\h*\|\h*`
- Replace with:   <-- a space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?:           # start non capture group
    [^|]+       # 1 or more non pipe
    \|          # a pipe, have to be escaped as it's special character for regex
  ){3}          # end group, must appear 3 times
  .*?           # 0 or more any character but new line, not greeedy
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \|            # a pipe, have to be escaped as it's special character for regex
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]